# Sending Mail Using spring boot and JavaMailSender with proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proxy, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email using JavaMailSender in spring boot. I have tried almost everything but still getting this error. Please suggest me what should I do In order to get my code working? Thanks!!!

here is my code for sending an email.

```
public void prepareAndSend(String recipient, String message) {
    SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
    mailMessage.setFrom("xxx@gmail.com");
    mailMessage.setTo(recipient);
    mailMessage.setSubject("test");
    mailMessage.setText(message);
    javaMailSender.send(mailMessage);
}
```

Application.properties file

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=*******
spring.mail.password= *******

#mail properties
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.15.1
-Dhttp.proxyPort=2120 
-Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.15.1
-Dhttps.proxyPort=2120
-Dhttps.proxySet=true 
-Dhttp.proxySet=true

server.use-forwarded-headers=true
```

I am getting the following error Exception when I try to run the code

```
2018-12-14 11:38:03.832 ERROR 2540 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com] with root cause

java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:319) ~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233) ~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938) ~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642) ~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295) ~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:501) ~[spring-context-support-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:421) ~[spring-context-support-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:307) ~[spring-context-support-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:296) ~[spring-context-support-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at com.bharti.firstspringbootproject.service.UserService.prepareAndSend(UserService.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.bharti.firstspringbootproject.controller.AuthenticateController.authenticateUser(AuthenticateController.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.bharti.firstspringbootproject.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at
```

Comment: Try using your smtp host as `spring.mail.host=smtp.googlemail.com`. And please also go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085856/java-mail-exception-error

Answer (score 1):

The JavaMail FAQ has instructions for [configuring JavaMail to use a proxy server](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#proxy).  If you're using JavaMail 1.6.0 or later, set the [`mail.smtp.proxy.host`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.proxy.host) and [`mail.smtp.proxy.port`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.proxy.port) properties.

Answer (score -1):

I already wrote the mail server using spring boot. but I didn't get this kind of issue. This seems network(proxy) issue. Please try without proxy.

Find below sample code for your reference.

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
```

I used MineMessage as below.

```
   MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
   MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
   helper.setFrom(systemEmail);
   helper.setTo(mailBacklog.getToAddress());
     if(mailBacklog.getSubject() != null) {
          helper.setSubject(mailBacklog.getSubject());
     }
   helper.setText(mailBacklog.getMessage());
   javaMailSender.send(message);
```

sample configuration (.yml)

```
spring:  
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
    password: xxxxxx
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it work if I am under proxy. Because the same code is working without proxy, but not with the proxy.